# Converting from RGB to LAB Color Space to Reduce Colors

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, color

In many papers I see the following:

> First we have to convert image from `RGB` to [`LAB`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space) color space to reduce colors then algorithm can run faster.

I can't understand this. How can this happen? What I read is that `Lab` color space has support for more colors than the other. But I see people says converting to `Lab` reduces the colors to better calculation. Why and how does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about [LAB Color Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space).

Its main advantage on RGB is by having 1 channel dedicated to the Luminosity of the Image and 2 others dedicated to the color information.

This means if you need to process only Luminosity / Color you can do that using LAB without having any effect on Color / Luminosity.